# How to apply a function on each row of a Spark Dataframe after groupby using Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 3.0.x in Java and we've a transformation requirement that goes as follows:

**A sample (hypothetical) Dataframe:**

```
+==============+===========+
| UserCategory | Location  |
+==============+===========+
| Premium      | Mumbai    |
+--------------+-----------+
| Premium      | Bangalore |
+--------------+-----------+
| Gold         | Kolkata   |
+--------------+-----------+
| Premium      | Moskow    |
+--------------+-----------+
| Silver       | Tokyo     |
+--------------+-----------+
| Gold         | Sydney    |
+--------------+-----------+
| Bronze       | Dubai     |
+--------------+-----------+
| ...          | ...       |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Let's say, we have a `UserCategory` column on which we need to perform a `groupby()`. Then on each row of the grouped data we need to apply certain function. The function is dependent on both the columns of the dataframe. E.g. we might generate a `CouponCode` based on how many users are there in a specific `UserCategory` and also the user `Location`. Point is, it has to have a groupby() before the row-by-row rule coming in. The expected output might be something like the following:

```
+==============+===========+============+
| UserCategory | Location  | CouponCode |
+==============+===========+============+
| Premium      | Mumbai    | IN01P      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Premium      | Bangalore | IN02P      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Premium      | Moskow    | RU03P      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Gold         | Kolkata   | IN01G      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Gold         | Sydney    | AU01G      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Silver       | Tokyo     | JP01S      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| Bronze       | London    | UK01B      |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| ...          | ...       | ...        |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

Now, if we were using PySpark, I could've leveraged pandas udf to achieve the functionality. But our stack is built on Java so that's not a possibility. I was wondering what could be a way to achieve the same in Java.

I was looking at the javadoc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/index.html), and it seems a groupby() on dataframe returns a [RelationalGroupedDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html). Then I browsed through the methods available on the `RelationalGroupedDataset` class, and the only one that looks promising is the [apply()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#apply-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-scala.collection.Seq-org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupType-) function. Unfortunately it doesn't have any documentation and the method signature looks a bit intimidating:

```
public static RelationalGroupedDataset apply(Dataset<Row> df,
                                             scala.collection.Seq<org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression> groupingExprs,
                                             RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupType groupType)
```

So, question is, is that the way to go? If so, then a dummy example of the apply() method would be very much appreciated. Else, if you could point me towards a different approach of achieving the same, that'd also be fine.

Comment: If you are looking for ways to write UDFs for grouped data, have a look at [UDAFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html)

Comment: @mck looks like UDAF will return 1 row per group. But that's not what I want. Do let me know if I'm missing anything here.

Comment: You can use UDAFs in window functions, which will allow it to add a column to each row

Comment: @mck thanks, will look into it. Do you have any examples handy, or links?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156320/spark-3-typed-user-defined-aggregate-function-over-window) is a good one - in Scala, but should be easily translated into Java, I think